# Setting up variables for optimizer in tensorflow eager execution

Tags: tensorflow

```
x=tfe.Variable(np.random.uniform(size=[166,]), name='x')

optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer()
optimizer.minimize(lambda: compute_cost(normed_data[:10], x))

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-9ff2a070e305> in <module>()
     23 
     24 optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer()
---> 25 optimizer.minimize(lambda: compute_cost(normed_data[:10], x))

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py in minimize(self, loss, global_step, var_list, gate_gradients, aggregation_method, colocate_gradients_with_ops, name, grad_loss)
    398         aggregation_method=aggregation_method,
    399         colocate_gradients_with_ops=colocate_gradients_with_ops,
--> 400         grad_loss=grad_loss)
    401 
    402     vars_with_grad = [v for g, v in grads_and_vars if g is not None]

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py in compute_gradients(self, loss, var_list, gate_gradients, aggregation_method, colocate_gradients_with_ops, grad_loss)
    471       if var_list is None:
    472         var_list = tape.watched_variables()
--> 473       grads = tape.gradient(loss_value, var_list, grad_loss)
    474       return list(zip(grads, var_list))
    475 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/backprop.py in gradient(self, target, sources, output_gradients)
    856     flat_grad = imperative_grad.imperative_grad(
    857         _default_vspace, self._tape, nest.flatten(target), flat_sources,
--> 858         output_gradients=output_gradients)
    859 
    860     if not self._persistent:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/imperative_grad.py in imperative_grad(vspace, tape, target, sources, output_gradients)
     61   """
     62   return pywrap_tensorflow.TFE_Py_TapeGradient(
---> 63       tape._tape, vspace, target, sources, output_gradients)  # pylint: disable=protected-access

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute '_id'
```

Can someone explain why I'm getting this error? "x" is the only stateful variable/weight I have for my "model/loss fnx" here (which is MLE of a joint pdf). Compute_cost works fine on its own unit test.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that there are operations in your `compute_cost` function that use numpy operations instead of TensorFlow operations. And TensorFlow cannot differentiate through those.

For example, consider the following:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
tf.enable_eager_execution()

v = tf.contrib.eager.Variable(2.0)

# x * v^2
def f(x):
  return np.multiply(x, np.multiply(v, v))

with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
  y = f(10.0)

# This next line will raise an error similar to what you observed.
print(tape.gradient(y, v)) 

# However, replacing the `np` operations with their equivalent
# `tf` operations will allow things to complete

def f(x):
  return tf.multiply(x, tf.multiply(v, v))

with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
  y = f(10.0)
print(tape.gradient(y, v)) # Correctly prints 40.0
```

So, it's most likely something similar where your `compute_cost` function is using numpy operations.

That said, this error message certainly has room for improvement, so you should consider filing a bug to improve that.

Hope that helps.