# Gradient erroneously returns none

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
print("\ncomputed 1")
x=tfe.Variable(np.random.uniform(size=[166,]), name='x', dtype=tf.float64)
print(compute_cost(tf.constant(normed_data[:10], dtype=tf.float64), x))

print("\ncomputed 2")
x=tfe.Variable(np.random.uniform(size=[166,]), name='x', dtype=tf.float64)
print(compute_cost(tf.constant(normed_data[:10], dtype=tf.float64), x))

print("\ncomputed 0")
x=tfe.Variable(np.zeros((166,)), name='x', dtype=tf.float64)
print(compute_cost(tf.constant(normed_data[:10], dtype=tf.float64), x))

print("\ncomputed 0")
x=tfe.Variable(np.zeros((166,)), name='x', dtype=tf.float64)
print(compute_cost(tf.constant(normed_data[:10], dtype=tf.float64), x))
```

Output:

```
computed 1
tf.Tensor(0.00627350861776064, shape=(), dtype=float64)

computed 2
tf.Tensor(0.0032756996843633264, shape=(), dtype=float64)

computed 0
tf.Tensor(19.318829784931626, shape=(), dtype=float64)

computed 0
tf.Tensor(19.318829784931626, shape=(), dtype=float64)
```

Clearly, the tfe.Variable x is affecting the loss function, so the gradient should not be None/0. Yet it is...

```
x=tfe.Variable(np.random.uniform(size=[166,]), name='x', dtype=tf.float64)
f_grad = tfe.gradients_function(lambda s: compute_cost(tf.constant(normed_data[:10], dtype=tf.float64), s), params=['s'])
print("\nGradient " + str(f_grad(x)))
```

Output:

```
Gradient [None]
```

Can someone explain what's wrong? Using Tensorflow 1.10.1 with eager execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `None` return value signifies that there is no dependency between the output of the function and the variable.

Looking at the `compute_cost` function you linked to, [I see a numpy operation (`np.log`) in there](https://github.com/richardrl/mil/blob/75f24bbd6aba8e2f788dcecd0592ca9c64dbc297/musk%20data%20test.ipynb#L175), which would break the "trace" of differentiable operations. Note that TensorFlow can only compute gradients through TensorFlow operations.

Similar to [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52137219/setting-up-variables-for-optimizer-in-tensorflow-eager-execution/52141970#52141970), replacing the numpy operation with the corresponding TensorFlow one ([`tf.log`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/log)) should do the trick.

Hope that helps.